# Searching an oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, search, meta

I have a number of documents that are in PDF,word and email formats how to store these documents that they can be searched by meta-data?

Answer (score 0):

Non Textual things like that can be stored in an Oracle database as a CLOB or BLOB field.
What sort of metadata do you want to be able to search on?